# Button onClick wont work

Tags: android, eclipse

following some tutorials i encountered a strange error...when i start it on my device it crashes instantly...why?
Also i tried 3 different ways to use onClick... whats the difference between those 3?
(the other 2 are commented out)

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="button1"
android:onClick="sendMessage" />





package com.example.a2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
 android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

String CopyText;
String editText1;
String editText2;

final Button button1 = new Button(this);




public void sendMessage(View view) 
{
button1.setText(editText1); 
}


/*
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) 
{

}
});
/*

  /*
OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    button1.setText(editText1);
}
};
*/



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: It seems you are new to android and don't know how to use it. Try reading Google's resources here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 1):

try this..

do that **initialization** and click inside your `onCreate`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cilcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });

    }
```

**EDIT :**

When an activity starts its life **onCreate()** is called. It is called only once in the lifecycle of an activity.

If you save the state of the application in a bundle (typically non-persistent, dynamic data in onSaveInstanceState), it can be passed back to onCreate if the activity needs to be recreated (e.g., orientation change) so that you don't lose this prior information. If no data was supplied, savedInstanceState is null.

Comment: ty it worked for me :) what is the "onCreate" function anyways? which kind of code do i have to place there?

Comment: @user3024088 check out my edit and also don't forget to accept my ans.

Comment: @user3024088 there is a tick near my ans click that.

Comment: cant find it sry...maybe i need to be registert? currently im logged in via FB...

Answer (score 1):

first :
solution to make button without any reference to layout and try to change the test of it

second :
the button id in layout is button_send and you try to access it with button1

and i think the third solution related to second problem